# Wordpress - only show posts where custom date and time meta is equal to or greater than right now

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm querying a custom post type, 'schedule', and sorting the posts by a custom meta field, '_broadcast_date' to try and create a tv guide sort of thing.

Here's the code from my plugin that registers the post type and custom meta:

```
/** Register Schedule Post Type */
add_action( 'init', 'hiblio_pt_schedule_init' );
function hiblio_pt_schedule_init() {
    $labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Scheduled Programmes', 'post type general name', 'hbl-plugin' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Scheduled Programme', 'post type singular name', 'hbl-plugin' ),
    'menu_name'          => _x( 'Scheduled Programmes', 'admin menu', 'hbl-plugin' ),
    'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Scheduled Programme', 'add new on admin bar', 'hbl-plugin' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'scheduled-programme', 'hbl-plugin' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add a Programme to the Schedule', 'hbl-plugin' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Scheduled Programme', 'hbl-plugin' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Scheduled Programme', 'hbl-plugin' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Scheduled Programme', 'hbl-plugin' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'Scheduled Programmes', 'hbl-plugin' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Scheduled Programmes', 'hbl-plugin' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Scheduled Programmes:', 'hbl-plugin' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No Scheduled Programmes found.', 'hbl-plugin' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Scheduled Programmes found in Trash.', 'hbl-plugin' )
    );

    $args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'hbl-plugin' ),
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => 'hbl-admin',
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'schedule' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
    'taxonomies'           => array( 'hbl-categories' ),
    'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_schedule_metaboxes'
    );

    register_post_type( 'schedule', $args );
}

/** Custom Meta for Schedule Post Type */
function add_schedule_metaboxes(){
    add_meta_box('hbl_schedule_meta', 'Programme Details', 'hbl_schedule_meta', 'schedule', 'normal', 'high');
}

/*** Schedule Meta Box */
function hbl_schedule_meta() {
    global $post;

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="schedulemeta_noncename" id="schedulemeta_noncename" value="' . 
    wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';

    $broadcastDate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_broadcast_date', true);
    echo '<label for="_broadcast_date">Broadcast Date</label><input type="date" name="_broadcast_date" value="' . $broadcastDate  . '" class="widefat" /><br /><br />';

    $broadcastTime = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_broadcast_time', true);
    echo '<label for="_broadcast_time">Broadcast Time</label><input type="time" name="_broadcast_time" value="' . $broadcastTime  . '" class="widefat" />';
}

/** Save schedule meta */
function hbl_save_schedule_meta($post_id, $post) {

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['schedulemeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
    return $post->ID;
    }

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID )) {
    return $post->ID;
    }

    $schedule_meta['_broadcast_date'] = $_POST['_broadcast_date'];
    $schedule_meta['_broadcast_time'] = $_POST['_broadcast_time'];

    foreach ($schedule_meta as $key => $value) {
    if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return;
    $value = implode(',', (array)$value);
    if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) {
        update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
    } else {
        add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
    }
    if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key);
    }

}

add_action('save_post', 'hbl_save_schedule_meta', 1, 2);
```

Here's the code from my page template:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' ); ?>

    <?php
        global $post;
        $args=array(
          'post_type' => 'schedule',
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'posts_per_page' => -1,
          'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
          'orderby' => '_broadcast_date',
          'order' => 'ASC'
        );
        $schedule_query = null;
        $schedule_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $schedule_query->have_posts() ) {
            while ($schedule_query->have_posts()) : $schedule_query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="scheduleItem">
                    <div class="scheduleItemImage" style="background-image: url(<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
                        } else {
                        echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/rewindBlank.jpg';
                        }
                    ?>)"></div>
                    <div class="scheduleItemInfoWrapper">
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <div class="scheduleItemContent">
                            <?php echo the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="scheduleItemDetails">
                            <span class="scheduleItemDate"><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_broadcast_date', true).'</span> @ <span class="scheduleItemTime">'.get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_broadcast_time', true)  ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile;
        }
        wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
    ?>

<?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>
```

What I'd like to do is alter the query somehow so that it will only return posts where the _broadcast_date and _broadcast_time meta is in the future, i.e. only upcoming broadcasts will be displayed. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show us how the broadcast date and time are being saved in the DB? This may change how you query. Also, it may not be possible within the context of a WP_Query- you may have to query the DB directly to accomplish this.

Comment: @MikelBitson Thanks for the reply, I've added the code from my plugin now

Comment: Can you open up the database, open the usermeta table, and search for the key like "%broadcast_date%"? This will show you the meta_value as it's saved in the database, this way we can see how we could query because we'll know the format the values are being saved as.

Comment: _broadcast_date is being stored as YYYY-MM-DD and _broadcast_time is HH:MM

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [**meta_query**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) like so: (Not tested, may need revision)

```
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'schedule',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
    'orderby' => '_broadcast_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => '_broadcast_date',
            'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_broadcast_time',
            'value' => date('H:i'),
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'TIME'
        ),
    )
);
$schedule_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

EDIT: Live long, vote often :D

Comment: It works for the date, but not for the time :( 

I tried changing the little h to a capital H in the time query as the times are being stored in 24hr format but that cancels out the date query and only shows posts where the time is later than the current time.

It seems like it's close to what I'm after but it's running `query1 OR query2` rather than `query1 AND query2`

Comment: Hey @user28419 I edited my post for the AND relation and the 24 hour time- if this still doesn't work we'll need to do some debugging.

Comment: Ignore my first comment, changing the H to a capital doesn't actually seem to alter the query, I don't think the time query is actually working at all

Comment: Having the meta-query to an AND operation on both the date and time is one issue. If it's 14:00 for example, a program at 03:00 tomorrow won't show up.

Comment: This might help with that http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11173/what-is-the-correct-way-to-compare-dates-in-a-wp-query-posts-meta-query

Comment: @MikelBitson I tried your new query but it doesn't return anything

Comment: If I altered my plugin so that I only have one field using a datetime format, rather than one for date and one for time, would I be able to query that more easily?

Comment: Yes it would. No doubt.

Comment: @KeithL I'll give that a go and report back. Thanks both of you for your help so far, much appreciated!

Comment: @KeithL Great points, man. Yeah, user28419 - I would agree with changing this to a datetime field. This would make life much easier.